# React Pie chart with range slider without using state

Tags: reactjs, svg, pie-chart, stateless

I want to draw pie chart in react .
when slider range changes the pie chart should change according to value of range slider.
We cant use state in the assignment.
problem is that i am new in react and dont know how to change child attribute (stroke-dasharray in my case) value from parent without using state which should be reflected on pie chart.

any one please help me .
my whole code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Raect Aiignment - PI Chart</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js"></script> -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@2.7.2/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
        <!--  chartkick dependency on chart.js -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-chartkick@0.3.0"></script>
        <style>
        .circle_style
        {
            fill: #f4fc16;
            stroke: #DF5C24;
            transition: stroke-dasharray 1s linear infinite
        }
        .svg_style {
            background: #f4fc16;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
            -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">

        const svgVars = {
            svgWidth: 100,
            svgHeight: 100,
            defaultRadius: 25,
            cX: 50,
            cY: 50,
            defaultStrokeWidth: 50, // 2*circleRadius = 50
        };

        const circumferenceWidth = () => Math.PI * 2 * svgVars.defaultRadius;
        var dashWidth = (rangeSliderValue = 50) => {
            return ( rangeSliderValue * circumferenceWidth() / 100).toFixed(3)  ;
        };


        class Slider extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <form id="slider_form" role="form">
                        <input type="range" min={0} max={100} defaultValue={25} step={1} onChange={this.props.doAfterSlide} />
                    </form>
                );
            }
        }

        class Head extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <h1>PI Chart with range slider</h1>
                );
            }
        }

        class Chart extends React.Component {
            render() {
                let cirStyle = {
                        strokeDasharray: `${ dashWidth() } ${ circumferenceWidth() }`,
                        strokeWidth: svgVars.defaultStrokeWidth
                }
                return (
                    <svg width={ svgVars.svgWidth } height={ svgVars.svgHeight } className="svg_style">
                        <circle r={ svgVars.defaultRadius } cx={ svgVars.cX } cy={ svgVars.cY } style={ cirStyle } className="circle_style" />
                    </svg>
                );
            }
        }

        class PieChart extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
                this.updatePiechart = this.updatePiechart.bind(this);
            }
            updatePiechart(e) {
                let sliderValue = e.target.value;
                let dw = dashWidth(sliderValue);

                console.log(dw);
                console.log("hello");
            }
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Head />
                        <Slider doAfterSlide={this.updatePiechart} />
                        <Chart />
                    </div>
                );      
            }
        }


        /**
         * Render
         * 
         */
        ReactDOM.render(
            <PieChart />,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the new dashWidth value in a global variable or property of the `PieChart` class, and pass this value to `Chart` through props.

Then call this.forceUpdate() to cause the `PieChart` to re-render when it changes.

Note, I would never do this in real code, instead I would use `state`, since this is exactly what `state` is meant to be used for. Not allowing the use of `state` is a really strange constraint for a assignment using React.